# Changing url based on id and getting values from local storage. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to access the **logged in** user's role by getting a value stored in `localStorage`, then based on that value I wanna set up my `url` and perform a `fetch` request. All of this is happening inside a `ContextProvider`.

My issue is that my `fetch` request is firing before I can obtain the value stored in `localStorage`.

Here is how I construct my url:

```
 const [userRole, setUrerRole] = useState(0);
 const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
 let userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');

 if (userID === 3){
   setUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/00666")
 }else if(userID === 1){
   setUrl(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"/api/v111/someexampleendpoint")
 }
```

and I use the hook,

```
  useMemo(() => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          setUserDetails(response);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);
```

Now the way I tried to do it originally is by creating a promise and chaining the functions but it didn't work.

```
function grabUserdStoredID(){
     let userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');

     if (userID === 3){
       setUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/00666")
     }else if(userID === 1){
       setUrl(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"/api/v111/someexampleendpoint")
     }
   return Promise.all
}


 grabUserdStoredID.then(
          useMemo(() => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          setUserDetails(response);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
   }, []);
  )
```

but it said that I cannot fire the hook in that way...

> How can I call a fetch request inside a context after I've obtained
>   values from `localStorage`?

Comment: You are doing wrong multiple things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of things going wrong here. I'm going to point out a few of them and give you an alternative structure at the end.

1. Your url can be derived from your state, so don't also store that in state.
2. Do not `useMemo` for an api call. `useMemo` is for caching computed values on render to prevent you from having to do it again unnecessarily. In this case you *do* want to put the results of your api call in state.
3. Fetch api calls with `useEffect` which then calls a state setter function after the fetch promise resolves. This way you can easily control the timing of the api calls with the dependency array.
4. `localStorage.getItem()` is not a problem here. It's synchronous api that returns a value immediately.

Putting this together, you end up with something like:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState()
  let userID = localStorage.getItem("userID")

  useEffect(() => {
    let url
    if (userID === "3") {
      url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/00666"
    } else if (userID === "1") {
      url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/api/v111/someexampleendpoint"
    }

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        setUserDetails(response)
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, [userID])

  return <div>Content Here</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tell me not only how but why I should do it this way. Your input was really appreciated!